# How to deal with voice change?

Tags: scales, voice, vocal-range, pitch, voice-change

I am a 14 year old boy and I think my voice is changing. Last year I used to nail notes from D4-G5 in my chest voice and I was always taking the high octave (even with the girls singing) but over the last month, anything above a C5 is starting to become pretty tiring for my voice. What should I do for singing practice now? My comfortable range now is more like F3-D5 in chest voice (I don't like to sing in falsetto). It used to be like A3-G5 or A5.

Comment: Step One: Learn to love the voice you have. Voices change, and fighting that change is very difficult. You'll feel a lot better about yourself as a singer if you see the good as well as the bad in the voice change.

Comment: What you'll lose at the top end will be compensated with a gain at the bottom end. Go with the flow. You're not going to retain the top end. Remember it with pleasure, and start enjoying the new lows - that you couldn't reach previously.

Comment: Possibly worrying - if your voice is anything like mine, your vocal range may continue sliding lower well into adulthood. I'm gaining my ability to hit the G below the C below Middle C and losing my ability to sing the C two octaves above Middle C.

Comment: I am not sure my voice will get crazy low cause my dad's is kind of average for a male in terms of pitch. still way way way deeper than mine.

Answer (score 6):

1.) Don’t freak out. Every boy goes through this. :)

2.) Don’t force those high notes - your vocal folds are growing so your voice is going to become less predictable - you’ll lose some high, gain some low, and crack between them occasionally.

3.) Do vocal warmups: regular vocal warmups will strengthen your voice and will ease the transition of your voice, making cracks and things less likely / noticeable.

4.) Keep singing, but be honest with yourself and what’s right for your voice. You can’t sing the highest parts anymore, and that’s okay. Start learning to sing the lower parts - your choir director really wants low voices and will be happy!

5.) Random fact: even after your voice “settles” it actually won’t reach maturity until your mid-30’s. So be kind: vocal warm-ups, never force, and lots of water = happy voice

Optional: If you can afford it, a voice teacher (specifically one who is classically-trained in vocal pedagogy) can do many wonders for your voice.

Comment: I think getting a voice teacher might be a good addition to this list - to help prevent any injury at such a young age.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - sure, I can put it in as optional. I initially left it out because not all folks are able to afford voice teachers

Comment: Yeah i understand. I will probably have to start singing lower parts with the other guys now. I will probably just sing in the lower comfortable octave of my voice now: A3-A4.

Comment: And the strange thing is I am not voice cracking like the normal teenage boy. i just have a different tone when singing which makes me sound a bit more manly, but my singing range right now is very similar to the girls in my class.

Comment: @akhilshah - it’s not strange, some kids crack a lot and others hardly do and there’s everything in between. By what you’ve told us, you’re a very normal teenage boy. If / when it (vocal cracking) does happen it’s normal. Your friends will probably tease you about it - that’s normal too. Regarding singing, the most important thing is that you’re sensitive to what is comfortable and not straining yourself. Higher ≠ better, and all voice types are necessary and celebrated in music.